# Evolution of Heinlein's treatment of homosexuality?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, sexuality

IIRC the treatment of homosexuality in Heinlein's writing changed a lot over time. My recollection is that in an early book (possibly *Stranger in a Strange Land*?), a sympathetic or authorial mouthpiece character refers to gay people as "poor cripples" or "confused" or something along those lines. By the time he wrote *I Will Fear No Evil*, he was describing humans as having 6 sexes, which are all the combinations of physically M/F with straight/bi/gay.

Can anyone fill in my vague recollections? Is there any evidence as to whether his attitudes actually evolved, or whether there was editorial censorship or self-censorship early on? In the 1942 *Beyond This Horizon*, there is a scene where two men trade notes on firearms in very macho fashion, and then one of them compliments the other on the shade of his nail polish. This could be taken at face value, or you could read it as Heinlein writing a scene that pushed the envelope as much as possible for marketable genre fiction in 1942. He did fight a series of sometimes ludicrous censorship battles with the freudian-minded editor of his juvenile novels.

[EDIT] A question like this really comprises two questions, one about what the author thought, and one about what he wrote. The link contributed by wcullen to material by Bill Patterson probably tells us as much as we're ever likely to know about #1, so I've edited the question to focus just on #2.

Comment: William H. Patterson wrote a rather detailed response on the website I linked. The actual question--"Did Heinlein change his views on homosexuality over the years?"-- is about 3/4 of the way down this FAQ page: http://www.heinleinsociety.org/2013/02/faq-frequently-asked-questions-about-robert-a-heinlein-the-person-2/

Comment: From the link: *a letter written in 1962, i.e., just after Stranger was published: You mentioned “homosexuality.” I’m a bit ashamed of the gentle sideswipe I gave the subject* This "sideswipe" may be the vaguely remembered "poor cripples" or "confused" remark that I referred to in the question. In general, I trust Patterson more on Heinlein's early life (i.e., the first volume of the biography), but re Heinlein's later life, IMO, Patterson turned to hagiography and often recorded Heinlein's own points of view, grudges, and anecdotes as if they were objective facts.

Comment: Why does an author's fictional work necessarily have to reflect his personal views?  In *Farnham's Freehold* white people were chattel slaves.

Comment: @KyleJones: You're right. That's why I made the edit to distinguish the two aspects of the question.

Comment: @Ben Crowell --This links to an excerpt of a  chapter by Wendy Pearson ("Science Fiction and Queer Theory") in the book 'The Cambridge Companion to Science Fiction' (E. James & F. Mendlesohn, Eds.) which discusses how writing sympathetically about homosexuality does not necessarily involve disrupting hetero-normativity. I thought this to be quite interesting, but it might not answer the quesiton: https://www.iml295.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Pearson.pdf

Comment: @wcullen: The Pearson article does have a brief discussion of a couple of Heinlein books on p. 2.

Comment: Don't have the text of 'Stranger' at hand, but my memory of it was Jill saying something like "Poor in-betweeners.  I don't think Mike will ever invite them to share water".

Comment: I feel that it is worth noting for Bob’s earlier work that he, along with every other SF author who tried to publish with...damn, don’t remember anymore. Campbell or Gernsback. Anyway, whichever one, he had a secretary who was infamously prudish and would cut the slightest suggestion of sex or sexuality from stories. This only spurred authors to find ways to slip things under the radar as a bit of a gag.

Comment: @Broklynite it was John Campbell, and the censorous person was Kay Tarrent.  Hence the protagonist of one of Laumer's stories being named Fleming Ayniss.

Comment: @OrganicMarble thank you, my memory isn’t what it was.